# Changing the name of a SQL database missing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

when changing the name of a SQL server 2005 database moving mdf and ldf files.

First i run a script in my program's install:

```
Alter Database [[DBNAME]] MODIFY NAME = [[RENAMEDBNAME]] 

Alter Database [[RENAMEDBNAME]] MODIFY FILE ( NAME =  [[DBNAME]], NEWNAME = [[RENAMEDBNAME]] )

Alter Database [[RENAMEDBNAME]] MODIFY FILE ( NAME =  [[DBNAME]_log], NEWNAME = [[RENAMEDBNAME]_log] )

Alter Database [[RENAMEDBNAME]] MODIFY FILE ( NAME =[[RENAMEDBNAME]]  , FILENAME  ='[DBPATH][RENAMEDBNAME].mdf'  )

Alter Database [[RENAMEDBNAME]] MODIFY FILE ( NAME =[[RENAMEDBNAME]_log]  , FILENAME  ='[DBPATH][RENAMEDBNAME]_log.ldf'  )
```

ALTER DATABASE  [[RENAMEDBNAME]] SET OFFLINE GO

then I move the files in code.

then in the next script I use

```
ALTER DATABASE  [[RENAMEDBNAME]] SET ONLINE GO
```

The tables are missing from the database - Any ideas?
Should I use backup and restore?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backup and restore is by far the easiest and most reliable way to do this. You can use the following script to accomplish what you want though:

```
/* Detach the database */
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [junk] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'junk'
GO

/* Move your files and reattach using this script */
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [junk2] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50\MSSQL\DATA\junk2.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50\MSSQL\DATA\junk2_log.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following article from Technet.  They are 2 things you seem to have wrong.

1. SET OFFLINE must be done before altering
2. You can only do it one file at a time.

Reference article is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg452698.aspx)

Comment: Do u mean after Alter Database [[DBNAME]] MODIFY NAME = [[RENAMEDBNAME]] ?